# Activity.RESULT_OK always return -1 while taking picture from camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to take picture from camera. **onActivityResult** Activity.RESULT_OK always return -1.

here is my code

```
final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);


  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     //this condition always false
    if (requestCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {//here Activity.RESULT_OK always return -1 

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {

            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap btm = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");              
            _ivDoc.setImageBitmap(btm);
        } 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because it's constant value is -1.

```
RESULT_OK
added in API level 1
int RESULT_OK
Standard activity result: operation succeeded.

Constant Value: -1 (0xffffffff)
```

and by the way you need to check the resultCode not the request code for OK Result.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
if (requestCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
```

with

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
```